# What happens when both nodes of a tree have the same weight while constructing a Huffman code?

Tags: coding-theory

In figure `1.21`, `e` and `n2` have same weight. Why do we put `n1` on the right and `g` on the left of the tree.

[image]

Comment: I think it is stability. Originally $f,d<g$ so when combined, $g=n_1$, g is still put on the left.

Comment: It doesn't matter which way you do it.  You could do it the other way and all the resulting code words would be the same lengths.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the choice is completely arbitrary. Whichever choice you make, the resulting code will be optimal. Any particular algorithm will have a specific kind of behavior. One can speculate why they made this particular choice here — perhaps they had a tie-breaking rule in mind, perhaps they wanted the most aesthetically pleasing tree — but it's not very important.